# VBA - Issue appending a created HTML element to a HEAD element

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, userform

I am trying to achieve a javascript 'bridge' between a UserForm Webbrowser control and the form itself. I feel like I am almost there now, see below. But I cannot seem to append the created script to the Head of the document loaded into the webbrowser. The error is "Object required" at line "head.appendChild (scriptEl)". I used msgbox to display head.innerHTML which shows all the HTML, and also scriptEl.innerHTML has the fully formed script element, so not sure why that error is happening.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim head As HTMLGenericElement
Dim scriptEl As HTMLScriptElement
Dim element As HTMLScriptElement



Set head = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")(0)
Set scriptEl = WebBrowser1.Document.createElement("script")

    scriptEl.Text = "function sayHello() { alert('hello') }"
    head.appendChild (scriptEl)
    WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript ("sayHello")

End Sub
```

Comment: `head.appendChild scriptEl`

Comment: Thanks, please submit an answer ill accept. any idea why the InvokeScript has an error now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following code:

```vb
' Add references
' Microsoft Internet Controls
' Microsoft HTML Object Library

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With WebBrowser1
        .Navigate "about:blank"
        Do Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And Not .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        .Document.parentWindow.execScript "function sayHello() { alert('hello') }"
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow.execScript "sayHello();"

End Sub
```